# How to secure Fabric API Key from APK decompilation?

Tags: android, crashlytics, apktool

While [decompiling](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apktool) my android app APK file, I have found the fabric ApiKey key in manifest file. How to secure Fabric API Key from APK decompilation?

I have done following code changes for hiding Fabric API key from manifest file. But still it is visible after APK decompilation.

I added my fabric API key

`FabricAPIKey=0123456789ABCDEF012345123456789ABCDEF012` 
in gradle.properties.

In build.gradle(Module)

```
...........
def FABRIC_API_ID = FabricAPIKey

    .....
    buildTypes {
            debug {
                ..........
                manifestPlaceholders  = [//this is used for defining the variable for manifest file
                    FABRIC_API_KEY:FABRIC_API_ID
                 ]
            }
    release{ ..........
                manifestPlaceholders  = [//this is used for defining the variable for manifest file
                    FABRIC_API_KEY:FABRIC_API_ID
                 ]
            }
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="${FABRIC_API_KEY}" />
```

Comment: Impossible in theory. If you're shipping the key along with the app, a sufficiently motivated hacker can eventually get to it, given a debugger and enough time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Seva's point should be well noticed - "a sufficiently motivated hacker can eventually get to it, given a debugger and enough time".

If you want, you can place the API key and Build secret in a fabric.properties file. Copy your api key out of your android manifest, and delete the line that reads: `<meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"/>`

Then make a file called fabric.properties and place this folder in the root of the module that applies crashlytics in its' build.gradle In the fabric.properies file, `add:apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE`

Once that's complete, refresh your dependencies to pull in the change: `./gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies`

Comment: When I do it I get Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml....

Answer (score 1):

Try to save that in `strings.xml` and refer that here.

Then manifest will only show resource id in int format.

But if you open the strings.xml file it will be retrieved.

Comment: I got this  build error "Crashlytics found an invalid API key: @string/fabric_api_key."

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            
            android:value="@string/fabric_api_key"/>

Comment: Are you using same code? android:value="@string/fabric_api_key"

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="@string/fab_api_key" />

This is mine